# asyncio + aiohttp, 2 different codes, but the execution speed varies at times, although they are described the same way

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

There are 2 asynchronous codes, one runs very fast, the second is quite slow, with the same number of requests, what could be the problem and how can this problem be solved?
the intervals for which the code is executed are marked in the code.

this is a slow option

```
async def request(url, params=None):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        async with session.get(url, params=params) as response:
            return await response.json()


async def get_entity(session, url, params=None):
    async with session.get(url, params=params) as response:
        return await response.json()


async def parse_all():
    start = time.time()
    result = (
        await request(url + 'api/v1/companies/', params={"limit": 50})
    )['_embedded']['companies']
    task_list = []
    print(time.time() - start)  # 0.4720320701599121
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(headers=headers) as session:
        for company in result:
            for page_count in range(1, len(company['_embedded']['leads']) // 250 + 2):
                task_list.append(
                    get_entity(
                        session,
                        url + 'api/v1/leads/',
                        {'page': page_count, 'company': company['id']}
                    )
                )
            for page_count in range(1, len(company['_embedded']['contacts']) // 250 + 2):
                task_list.append(
                    get_entity(
                        session,
                        url + 'api/v1/contacts/',
                        {'page': page_count, 'company': company['id']}
                    )
                )
        print(time.time() - start)  # 0.4190201759338379
        return await asyncio.gather(*task_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(parse_all())
    print(time.time() - start)  # 15.692176580429077
```

But actually fast. What's the difference?

```
async def request(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.json()


async def parse():
    start = time.time()
    task = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(1, 101):
            task.append(
                request(
                    session, f'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/{i}')
            )
        print(time.time() - start)
        return await asyncio.gather(*task)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(parse())
    print(time.time() - start) # 0.44432830810546875
```

Comment: Are you making the same requests in both examples? It doesn’t look like it. Are you sure that the difference isn’t the response time from the servers?

Comment: @dirn In the first test version, it was written when I was just studying, there is a response time of +- 250mc, in the second there is a response time of 250-350mc for a closed database, but with asynchronous execution, one code is asynchronously executed, in the second it is already synchronous....